# Get a value in first element of json array of gitAPI response in shell script

Tags: json, bash, shell, github-api

I'm getting the latest release's browser download url of a specific git repository using GIT API.

```
Curl command : curl -i https://api.github.com/repos/$owner/$repo/releases
```

It gives JSON array as a response.

Let's say, Given repo has 5 release.

I want to get "browser_download_url" value of the 1st element in JSON response.

What is the command can be used in shell script?

Comment: have a try `curl blahblah | jq '.[0] | .browser_download_url'`. install `jq` if you don't have

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't want to use the `-i` switch, that'll just mess with the json output.

Second, if you reviewed github's api documentation, you could get the data you want directly by using the correct url. The first item in the list of releases will be the latest published release... so get the latest.

Finally, you could use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to drill down to the assets you want to retrieve and get the url(s).

```
$ curl https://api.github.com/repos/$owner/$repo/releases/latest \
    | jq '.assets[].browser_download_url'
```

If you want a specific named release asset, you can select from the array of assets using the name using [`select/1`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#select(boolean_expression)).