# Git log - show merge request ID

Tags: git, gitlab

How do I find the merge request ID based on the commit ID or the last merge request? I want to include merge request ID in the CURL request but I'm unable to find the ID using the `git log` command.

```
http://10.10.10.10/api/v4/projects/9/merge_requests/67/notes
```

Comment: Note that "merge requests" are specific to GitLab: they don't exist in Git proper. If GitLab doesn't put them into lower-level Git parts, you won't be able to get them from Git itself, only from GitLab.

Comment: Didn’t the two answers here answer your question properly?

Answer (score 0):

You might need first to list merge requests, possibly filtering them by state, and [take the first one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49549371/6309) (using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/): `| jq '.[0]`).
See [List project merge requests](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#list-project-merge-requests):

```
GET /projects/:id/merge_requests?state=opened
curl --header "Private-Token: askljdhakjdlsa" "http://10.10.10.10/api/v4/projects/9/merge_requests?state=opened"
```

Comment: Can I find it using the commit id? because I can get the commit ID using the `git log` and there can be multiple merge requests at the same time and I might end up choosing wrong merge request. If I can search using commit id then I'll find the right merge request

Comment: @anon The first "sha" is part of the answer, which means you can use jq to filter by sha, looking for your specific commit.

Answer (score 0):

`Gitlab` stores, next to branches and tags, extra `merge-requests/...` references that point at Merge Request commits. You can view these running `git ls-remote` :

```
$ git ls-remote origin
ed228a67a...    HEAD
7215f3432...    refs/heads/cache
4ed228a67...    refs/heads/master
...
d2cc93ae3...    refs/merge-requests/1023/head    # current commit for MR #1023
a888aabaf...    refs/merge-requests/1023/merge
...
```

---

You can pull these references to your local repo, for example by updating the refspec in your config (adapted from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/piscisaureus/3342247)) :

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:joyent/node.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    fetch = +refs/merge-requests/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/mr/*   # <- add this line
```

then run `git fetch`.

You should now see `origin/mr/{xxx}` references in the output of git log, and use these names in other commands.

You can for example check if a commit *is* a pull request :

```
git for-each-ref refs/remotes/origin/mr --points-at <commit-ish>
```

Comment: GitHub? This question is about GitLab merge requests though.

Comment: @VonC: yeah, but the OP tagged it with [tag:github]. I'm about to remove that tag...

Comment: reworded my answer to match Gitlab setup